# Calculating length of common boundary lines of two polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, length, borders

I have a map consisting various district. How can I estimate the length of the common boundary shared by any two corresponding districts/polygons in QGIS?

For example if a polygon "A" shares a common boundary with polygons, "B", "C" and "D". Then what would be the length of the boundary between polygon "A-B", "A-C" and "A-D"?

I have calculated the neighboring polygon using the following in field calculator

```py
aggregate( 
  layer:='file_districts',
  aggregate:='concatenate',
  expression:= DIST_ID,
  concatenator:=', ',
  filter:=touches($geometry, geometry(@parent))
)
```

Now i want to estimate the length of each of the neighbor polygon.

[image: example]

Comment: What have you tried so far and what does not work? Please also share images/screenshots of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Is this a display issue, or do you need the length for further processing?

Comment: I had already obtained the neighborhood of the polygon,need their length as a separate attribute

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

> *Preamble:* this solution was being written before the moment when the author demonstrated his efforts in the field calculator.

In QGIS I can suggest using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume we have a layer `'units_1'` (yellow) with its corresponding attribute tables accordingly, see image below.

[image: input]

### Case 1. With aggregation

With the following query, it is possible to estimate the length of the common boundary shared by any two corresponding districts/polygons.

```sql
SELECT
    u11.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(u12.id || ', len:' || round(st_length(st_intersection(u11.geometry, u12.geometry)), 4), "; ") AS "neighbor_info"
FROM
    "unit_1" AS u11, "unit_1" AS u12
WHERE
    st_intersects(u11.geometry, u12.geometry)
    AND u11.id <> u12.id
GROUP BY
    u11.id
ORDER BY
    u11.id ASC
```

The output Virtual Layer with its Attribute table will look as following

[image: output1]

### Case 2. Without aggregation

In case if no aggregation has to be conducted then proceed with the following query

```sql
SELECT
    u11.*,
    u12.id || ', len:' || round(st_length(st_intersection(u11.geometry, u12.geometry)), 4) AS "neighbor_info"
FROM
    "unit_1" AS u11, "unit_1" AS u12
WHERE
    st_intersects(u11.geometry, u12.geometry)
    AND u11.id <> u12.id
ORDER BY
    u11.id ASC
```

Then the new output Virtual Layer with its Attribute table will look as following

### [image: output2]

Answer (score 6):

Similar to @Taras's answer, you can create a virtual layer to get the actual border lines, and then compute their length (or display them, or label them, or ...)

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query.

```sql
select a.id as poly1_id, b.id as poly2_id, 
      st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry, 
      st_length(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry)) as border_length
from my_layer a
    join my_layer b 
        ON st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
            AND a.id < b.id
```

[image]

Note that if your layer is in lat/longs (4326), the you should use
`st_length(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry),true) as border_length` instead. This version of [`st_length`](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html#p6) will return a distance in meters instead of degrees.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the length of the border the current polygon shares with all bordering polygons, use this expression that creates an array:

```
    array_foreach (
        overlay_touches (@layer, $geometry),
        length (intersection ($geometry, @element))  
    )
```

Convert it to a string with `array_to_string()`, add the `$id` to identify the polygons and add other modifications (see below).

*A polygon layer with an expression-generated label, based on the expression from above, that generates a text-string list of length with all neighboring polygons (see below for the exact expression used here):*

[image]

- The expression used to generate the red line in the screenshot, using Geometry generator:

  ```
  if ($id = 1, intersection ( $geometry, overlay_touches (@layer, $geometry)[0]),'')
  ```
- To generate the length of the common boundary line of polygons `b` and `c`, stored in the field named `name`, use this expression (change layer name and value in lines 2 and 6):

  ```
  if (
      name = 'b', 
      length(
          intersection ( 
              $geometry, 
              geometry (get_feature (@layer, 'name', 'c'))
          )
      ),
      ''
  )
  ```
- The expression used to generate the label in the screenshot - can be used without changes on any polygon layer:

  ```
   'Length border of polygon '  || 
   $id || ' with: '  ||  '\n'  ||  
   array_to_string (
       array_foreach (
           overlay_touches (@layer, $id),
           '   - polygon'  || 
           @element || ': ' || 
           round (
               length (
                   intersection (
                       $geometry, 
                       geometry (
                           get_feature_by_id (
                               @layer, 
                               @element
                           )
                       )
                   )
               ), 
               3
           ) 
       )
   )
  ```