# "Duplicate column name" error when calculating length of shared boundaries between multiple polygons using Virtual Layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, overlapping-features, virtual-layer, borders

Similarly to the poster from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360760/calculating-length-of-common-boundary-lines-of-two-polygon-in-qgis), I am trying to calculate the length of the boundaries between several polygons. I have two types of polygons (1:blue and 2:pink), but I don't think that really matters.

[image]

I went as far as the user in [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360760/calculating-length-of-common-boundary-lines-of-two-polygon-in-qgis), i.e., I calculated the neighboring polygons, and according to the comment in the post, I tried using the code in the second answer:

```sql
select 
    a.ID as poly1_id,
    b.ID as poly2_id, 
    st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry, 
    st_length(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry)) as border_length
from
    groupe_layers a
join
    groupe_layers b ON st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
                        AND a.ID < b.ID
```

I replaced id by ID, and the layer name by "groupe_layers" (my layer name). Other than that, I left it as is.

Here is my table of attributes:
[image]

When I enter <kbd>Ok</kbd> after adding the query, a red ruban appears saying:

> la couche n'est pas valide = the layer is not valid
>
> "La couche n'est pas valide: La couche
> ?query=select%20a.ID%20as%20poly1_id,%20b.ID%20as%20poly2_id,%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20st_intersection(a.geometry,%20b.geometry)%20as%20geometry,%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20st_length(st_intersection(a.geometry,%20b.geometry))%20as%20border_length%0D%0Afrom%20groupe_layers%20a%0D%0A%20%20%20%20join%20groupe_layers%20b%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ON%20st_intersects(a.geometry,%20b.geometry)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AND%20a.ID%20%3C%20b.ID&uid=ID
> n'est pas une couche valide et ne peut pas être ajoutée à la carte.
> Raison : virtual Query execution error on DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
> "groupe_layers"; CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "groupe_layers" USING
> QgsVLayer(Géométries_simples_9e08b9a6_57fe_4dda_92d2_cfc74989e619);: 1
>
> - duplicate column name: geometry"

[Here is](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JWNm7f6GM_HNQiFKtclASNI2gUxtEW2y?usp=sharing) my layer with the data. The projection system is RGF93 / Lambert93.

Does someone have a lead on where my problem is? Something with the `geometry` column?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what happens when you run the sql?

Comment: Hello, thank you! there is a ruban appearing saying that the layer is not valid. The message is too long to be pasted here, so I will edit my post to include the error message.

Comment: Hello, I just copied the code from the post I was trying to get the solution from, but it may not be useful here (it's more of a postcode). I tried removing all that section, and it is still not working though.
select a.ID as poly1_id, b.ID as poly2_id, 
      st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry, 
      st_length(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry)) as border_length
from groupe_layers

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your data ?

Comment: Yes, I tried your answer in the other post, but got stuck at the first bit of code, with an error message too. I added a link to the post to download the shape file - is it what you meant to share data? Is there a better way to share data here?

Comment: Make sure to enter the SQL query in the virtual layer `query` box, **not** in the upper `embedded layers` section

Comment: @Taras regarding the ID comparison, it is there to return a single border line between two polygons

Comment: It doesn't matter what they are, as long as they are different for every polygon. For example based on the locale, we could have `AA > B` or `AA < B`, but it doesn't matter here which one is "more" or "less", as long as we can compare the two. The `intersects()` will return that `polygon 1` intersects `polygon 2` and that `polygon 2` intersects `polygon 1` so we have a duplicated combination and therefore a duplicated border. By comparing the ID and keeping the combination when "first ID < second ID" whichever is the first or second, we end up with a single border.

Comment: In fact the query would work just as well if we use `a.ID > b.ID` :-)

Comment: So, `a.ID > b.ID` is a different way of saying `a.ID <> b.ID`, is not it?

Comment: @Taras not at all. Using `<>` would lead to duplicates. You can use `<` or `>`, it doesn't matter since both will return only a single row when comparing `record1 vs record2` and `record2 vs record1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After bringing a sample of your data into QGIS

[image: input]

and using the following query

```sql
SELECT
    a.ID as poly1_id,
    b.ID as poly2_id,
    st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry,
    st_length(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry)) as border_length
FROM
    "groupe_layers" a
JOIN
    "groupe_layers" b ON st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
                        AND a.ID < b.ID
```

I was able to recreate the initial error

[image: error]

> Query execution error on DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "groupe_layers"; CREATE
> VIRTUAL TABLE "groupe_layers" USING
> QgsVLayer(groupe_layers_0504744b_5da5_48f2_bdc4_eecdf081e566);: 1 -
> duplicate column name: geometry_1994

QGIS induces this error because you already have a column in you original layer that is called `"geometry"`.

**Solution:** Renaming the `"geometry"` field. There are many approaches available on this topic, however, I will encourage using the `RMC > Fields > Edit...` and renaming the
`"geometry"` column into e.g. `"geom2"`. Another approach is the ["Rename field"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#rename-vector-field) algorithm, but then you will work with a new layer i.e. the result of the "Rename field" algorithm.

And then it is possible to achieve the desired output:

[image: output]