# Calculating length of common boundary with virtual layer in QGIS problem with output

Tags: qgis, polygon, length, borders

I'm calculating the length of common borders of 10 sets of polygons with the solution posted in this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/360776

In 8 of the 10 datasets everything works fine, but in two of them I have the problem that the output is a point layer, instead of a line layer. In one of the two cases, I was able to fix this by running "Repair Geometries". In the other case, repairing doesn't help.

Any ideas what could be the issue and how I could find a woraround?

Here's the code I'm using:

```sql
SELECT
  a.UUID_GIS AS poly1_id,
  b.UUID_GIS AS poly2_id,
  st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry) AS geometry,
  st_length(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry)) AS border_length
FROM "input1" a
  JOIN "input1" b
    ON st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
      AND a.UUID_GIS < b.UUID_GIS
```

If needed, you can [download the data here](https://c.web.de/@1055844442516232793/rqI9KNdWRTKfJekTtArivA).

Comment: I get a mix of points, linestrings, multilinestrings running this query on both your sample layers. Is your issue getting only points ? (Points are expected as there are polygons assembled in grids in your layer, with points as only common vertex).

Comment: yes, there have to be points in the output, due to polygons that only touch at their vertex. In fact I don´t need the points, as the length of common borders is 0. The issue is as you said, that sometimes I get an output with only points, with an error massage that linestrings/multilinestrings cannot be added to the point layer. But sometimes it´s the other way around and I get the output as line layer with the information of the border length. Maybe it has something to do with the order of appearance of point / lines? So if a point is identified first, the output is a point layer?

Comment: One thing you can do is add a condition for : Where St_geometryType(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom))  IN ('ST_LineString','ST_MultiLineString') to exclude Points or Point collections

Comment: I tried to add the code, but there is no output. Did I integrated at the right position? I´m not really good with SQL... 
`SELECT
    a.ID_FINAL as poly1_id,
    b. ID_FINAL as poly2_id,
    st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry,
    st_length(st_intersection(a.geometry, b.geometry)) as border_length
FROM
    "TestAusschnitt" a
JOIN
     "TestAusschnitt" b ON st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
                        AND a. ID_FINAL < b. ID_FINAL
      WHERE St_geometryType(st_intersection(a.geometry,b.geometry)) IN ('ST_LineString','ST_MultiLineString')`